# Why doesn't javascript parse HTML from fetch?

Tags: javascript, dom, fetch

I'm creating a chrome extension that scrapes photos from various websites. I have the URLs of each website and I want to fetch and parse those websites, and then grab specific `img` elements by class or ID.

I'm using the Javascript `fetch()` function together with `DOMParser` to parse the HTML and it returns the Document successfully, but any DOM query returns empty NodeLists / HTMLCollections.

```
fetch("www.example.com")
.then(res => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(res, "text/html");
    console.log(htmlDoc.querySelectorAll('h1'))
})
```

This gives me an empty NodeList. Why?? And how can I get the elements I'm looking for?

Comment: I think you need to do `res.text()` or `res.body()`.  Check the [Fetch Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) documentation.

Comment: The point Amy is making is that you are attempting to parse a DOM out of a Response object rather than the text returned from the server.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Whats the difference? And what would the solution look like?

Comment: @max - please see the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to parse the response before you use it. Like this:

```js
fetch("//randycasburn.com")
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(html => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
    console.log(htmlDoc.querySelector('span').textContent)
  })
```

Otherwise by passing `res` itself a DOM will be created and `res` will be casted to a string (`[object Response]`), which results in this DOM: (note no H1)

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>[object Response]</body>
</html>
```